# how to change smarty template location?

Tags: smarty

I am trying to change the template folder location is there anyway off doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set your template_dir on the Smarty object:

```
$smarty->template_dir = "/path/to/templates";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have extended the Smarty-class, you just have to write this in your class that extends the Smarty-class:

```
$this->template_dir = "template/folder";
```